# Use StreamWriter with BinaryFormatter

Tags: c#, serialization, stream, streamwriter

I am developing a server-client application and I want to serialize a List of strings on the server side and send it to client side.
I want to do the serialization using the `BinaryFormatter` class as follows:

```
List<String> myList = new List<String>();
ceva.Add("A");
ceva.Add("B");
ceva.Add("C!");
BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
binaryFormatter.Serialize(writer, myList);
```

My problem is that the `writer` streams is of type `StreamWriter`  and the `Serialize` method expects as a first argument an object of type `Stream`.

Is there any way I can use my writer of `StreamWriter` type the way I try here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`StreamWriter.BaseStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.streamwriter.basestream) property as a first argument of the `Serialize` method:

```
binaryFormatter.Serialize(writer.BaseStream, myList);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use like this.

```
List<String> myList = new List<String>();
ceva.Add("A");
ceva.Add("B");
ceva.Add("C!");
BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
binaryFormatter.Serialize(writer.BaseStream, myList);
```